# Revenue Cat firebase integration events need to don't track sandbox purchases

Tags: firebase, revenuecat, firebase-extensions

Revenue cat firebase integration events need to don't track sandbox purchases. I tried to disable in firebase extension Test events tracking, but still getting events with environment SANDBOX. How can i disable sandbox purchase tracking to firebase?

[image: Event log]

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution? We have the same issue